How to work with `complete -F _start_kubectl` when alias contains `--kubeconfig`?
I've encountered the issue with kubectl alias completion, which when kubectl with --kubeconfig it won't automatic complete by Tab.
But when I using full kubectl command (to expand via control + option + e), it will work.
System info:

osx 14.3.1
bash-completion@2 installed

local settings:
$ type kk
kk is aliased to 'kubectl --kubeconfig ~/.kube/8/config'

$ complete -p kk
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nosort -F __start_kubectl kk

$ cat ~/.inputrc
# allow iso-latin1 characters to be inserted
set convert-meta                   on
# don't strip characters to 7 bits when reading
set input-meta                     on
set completion-ignore-case         on
set show-all-if-ambiguous          on
set show-all-if-unmodified         on
set mark-symlinked-directories     on
set print-completions-horizontally on
set enable-bracketed-paste         off
set colored-stats                  on
set skip-completed-text            on

details (in video):
https://streamable.com/poigy6

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4219/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-for-command-aliases

thanks @Tblue, the detail steps has been added :)

get clue from @Tblue, and the alias completion works perfected with cykerway/complete-alias
steps:

download and source complete-alias :
$ curl -o ~/.config/complete_alias -fsSL https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias/raw/master/complete_alias
$ source ~/.config/complete_alias

# verify
$ type _complete_alias


set completion function to alias from command line ( debug purpose ):
$ alias kk='kubectl --kubeconfig ~/.kube/8/config'
$ complete -F _complete_alias kk

# verify
$ kk -n <tab>


or in rc file:
alias k1='kubecolor --kubeconfig ~/.kube/1/config'
alias k2='kubecolor --kubeconfig ~/.kube/2/config'
alias k3='kubecolor --kubeconfig ~/.kube/2/config'

source ~/.config/complete_alias
complete -o nosort -o bashdefault -o default -F _complete_alias $(alias | sed -rn 's/^alias ([^=]+)=.+kubec.+$/\1/p' | xargs)



result:

